# Apply Hidden Markov Model on specific Problem

Tags: hidden-markov-model

First let me show this picture of my HMM Model.

[image]

Experimentally I get the High and Low values, whereas the 
states {|-1>, |0>, |1>} are unknown. Although I know that when I measure
High signal I have |-1>. Also transition from |-1> to |1> are forbidden.

I heard that using a Markov Model here might be good to analyze 
a given time trace and get information about the hidden states.
If I understand the Idea correctly the HMM gives me the most likely
time trace given some transition probabilities. Then I optimize 
this time trace regarding my missing transition parameters ?

I'm glad for any help you can provide me. Also for good resources on 
how to implement Baum-Welch or Viterbi.

Okay thanks for the comment.

My question is:

What is the best and most time efficient way to get the transition rates between the hidden 
states ?

Comment: This is a good description of your situation / problem. Can you clarify what your question is exactly?

Answer (score 1):

here you go-  [link] https://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/asr/2012-13/asr03-hmmgmm-4up.pdf

I have understood HMM from these 3 videos- 
[link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3qrns5f3Fw
[link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjlhpaDXihE
[link] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sGEF-e82yY

transition probabilities would be calculated in training phase.[Forward-backward Algo]